# I have a sharepoint page without ribbon, I need to edit and add webpart to page, How can anybody knows please tell me with link

Tags: 2013, designer

I have a sharepoint home page(abchome.aspx) with out ribbon, now i want to edit page and add webpart, without ribbon how can i edit and add webpart, please tell me anybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending

```
?ToolPaneView=2&pagemode=edit
```

at the end of the url, the page will open in edit mode.

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/SitePages/default.aspx?ToolPaneView=2&pagemode=edit
```